# How to check if video have visually corrupted frames?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, corruption

I'm using ffmpeg to convert and analyze video, mostly avi to mkv. Sometimes video that I work on have one frame corrupted in random place, , it looks like:

[Digital scramble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErUPb.jpg)

How to check if frame is visually corrupted in ffmpeg?

It's not file corruption (not byte corruption), I know that because this video artifact is present in source file, it's just visual corruption.

This command line gives error free result: 
        ffmpeg -i myinput.avi {params} out.mkv 2> error_log.txt

How to find if similar pattern is on any more frames in video file? Can something from signalstats could be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found so far is to use ffprobe and force to count the frame, which takes a little more time than the usual way described above ..

```
ffprobe -v error -hide_banner -i $mediaFile -threads 0 -count_frames  -show_format \
-show_streams -print_format json 2>error.log
```